Flutter Container with decoration color listening to provider value
I simply want to have a Container where the color inside the decoration is set to a value of a provider (listen: true).
Like this:
child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              defaultBorderRadius,
            ),
          ),
...

But that is failing with:

Tried to listen to an InheritedWidget in a life-cycle that will never
be called again. This error typically happens when calling Provider.of
with listen to true, in a situation where listening to the
provider doesn't make sense, such as:

initState of a StatefulWidget
the "create" callback of a provider

This is undesired because these life-cycles are called only once in
the lifetime of a widget. As such, while listen is true, the
widget has no mean to handle the update scenario.

But I don't quite get it. Why couldn't I listen to a value here? Its not a button tap or anything. It is the background color of a container.
Weirdly enough: When setting the color to a simple static value, and changing it afterwards to the provider value, and then hot reload, it is working as expected! Even updating is working fine. Just the init is somehow failing.
What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more information!

What widget is the context coming from? Can you include more code that shows it?

Do you have more code to show? As an initial assumption, I guess you'd need a separate function for changing the color with notifyListeners() in it

the problem is not changing the color. The problem is that Flutter is not even building the widget...

According to provider package docs, When You try to call Provider.of<ThemeProvider> inside a Create method or State.initState(in your case create method) you need to set listen variable to false in order to make that work:
child: AnimatedContainer(
    duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).color, // <--- add this
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
       defaultBorderRadius,
     ),
  ),

